# woocommerce tier price(Quantity based pricing)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hello i want to add tier price in woocomerce like this
 i want to set quantity based price(Tier price)
For eg.

```
    QTY           Price
    1-99            $50
    100-249         $90

Also based on tier price
“Starting at $x.xx” will be dynamically generated based on the lowest tiered price entered into the system.
```

How is it possible with woocomerce  ecommmece plugin? Is there addon require please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

The [Dynamic Pricing](http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/) extension will let you set quantity-based prices :)

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce does not ship with quantity/tier/wholesale pricing capabilities.

You need to use some kind of extension like [WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing & Discounts](http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-discounts/7119279) or other alternatives.

You could also develop your own method to do so but this is not a good choice having in mind that most of the extensions already available are really cost effective.